# Trying to make a div appear on hover using absolute position. Need help centering it

Tags: html, css, position, dropdown

As title suggests I'm trying to make a div appear on hover of an anchor. I'm using a pseudo element to show a 'triangle' above the div.

Instead of posting code here,

[link to it](https://jsfiddle.net/7nfbxvxw/)

here's the HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="menu__item has-sub">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">Parent</a>
        <ul class="menu menu__sub">
            <li class="menu__item"><a href="javascript:void(0);">item 1 child 1</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a href="javascript:void(0);">item 1 child 2</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a href="javascript:void(0);">item 1 child 3</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a href="javascript:void(0);">item 1 child 4</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a href="javascript:void(0);">item 1 child 4</a>/li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Sorry about all the css I'm using sass so just decompiled it into css.

My problem is that I can't get the container to always be centered around the parent item because I'm using absolute positioning and a right/left hack to position it.

I have no idea how to do this properly so if anyone can help I would love you long time!

Also if you need me to clean up the css I'll try it is a hefty 81 lines but I wanted to show the full picture.

- Edit for clarification: I need the box to always be in the center of the parent text (in this case parent) but if parent text is changed to asdfasdfasdf I need to box to also be centered.

Basically the box must always be drawn center out regardless of parent text or content

ie:

```
                  Some Long Text Here
                   -------^-------
                   |   Content   |
                   |   Content   |
                   |   Content   |
                   ---------------

                       Text
               ----------^-----------
               |   Longer Content   |
               |   Longer Content   |
               |   Longer Content   |
               ----------------------
```

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/7nfbxvxw/1/?

Comment: Do you need to center the list, or the triangle?

Comment: @Gust Need to center the entire box, triangle should always be in the top center of the div, will clarify in post

Comment: @Nenad still breaks if the text is longer

Comment: Sorry if i'm retaggin you @GustvandeWal can't edit last comment

Answer (score 0):

Add width to your parent item

```
.menu__item > a {
    color: black;
    display: block;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 3;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center; /* add this */
    width: 165px; /* And this (this width should be same as .menu__sub class' width)*/
}
```

Remove right attribute and add 0 padding left and margin

```
.menu__sub {
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
 /* remove right */
    width: 165px;
    padding-left: 0; /* Add this */
    margin: 0 auto; /* and this */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `.menu__item` class you just need to removed the `display: inline-block` and add `text-align: center;`

In your `.menu-sub` you need to set both left and right to zero `left: 0; right: 0;` and add `text-align: center` to make it center;

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7nfbxvxw/7/)